# I created a GUI with gpio access in java and tested sucessfully in netbeans IDE. But when I runs in Raspberry pi it showing the following error

Tags: raspbian, java, xorg, pi4j

[image]following image showing the error while running the JAVA GUI application.I use the following command to run the jar file by adding class path of the pi4j lib.

Comment: cannot see the image or the command used.

Comment: If you are programming GUI in Java, you might want to read about JavaFX.  Everything I see says that JavaFX is the successor to Swing.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you want to do. It seems that the java program does not get access to a running X11 server. Do you run X11 on your pi? If so, then physically connecting keyboard, mouse and screen to it would probably solve your problem.

If you want the program running on the pi to use the X11-server of the machine you are running ssh from, then simply add the option `-X` to your `ssh` command, like so:

```
ssh -X pi@raspberrypi
```

and the pi will display the UI on your local machine.

Comment: Although that screenshot is in a GUI terminal, it *could* be an ssh session -- something the OP left ambiguous.  So good point.